# Multiplying a categorical variable with a dummy in regression

Tags: r, regression, dummy-variable

I am trying to run a regression that has scores regressed with a female dummy ( taking a value of 0 or 1) and I also have country for that female. I am trying to create a fixed effect on the regression where I have female interacted with country, but every method I try does not work since I am multiplying numeric with a factor

I have tried using fastdummies, but that did not work. I also tried using country-1 method, and trying to multiply with female with no success.

```
#first wrong
olss1= lm(pv1math ~ female + I(ggi*female) + factor(country) +  factor(year) + I(female * factor(country)), data = f1)
# second wrong
olss1= lm(pv1math ~ female + I(ggi*female) + factor(country) +  factor(year) + factor( female * country ), data = f1)
```

Error messages are that I cannot multiply factor with numeric

Comment: It is, in general, not sufficient to post an error message. When posting to SO examples should be reproducible which means giving complete code and data needed so that anyone else can copy and paste it into their R session and get the same error message.  See instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.

Answer (score 1):

The * operator in the formula will give interactions as well as lower order terms. Here is an example:

```
country <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")
female <- c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
y <- 1:6

fm <- lm(y ~ country * female)
fm
```

giving:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ country * female)

Coefficients:
    (Intercept)         countryB           female  countryB:female  
            3.0              2.0             -1.5              1.5
```

Also we can check the model matrix

```
model.matrix(fm)
```

giving

```
  (Intercept) countryB female countryB:female
1           1        0      1               0
2           1        0      1               0
3           1        0      0               0
4           1        1      1               1
5           1        1      0               0
6           1        1      1               1
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 2 3
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$country
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't need the `I()` here. `*` alone will perform an interaction, whereas `I()` will execute an arithmetic operation *before* the regression.

Compare:

```
lm(pv1math ~ ggi*female, data=dat)$coefficients
# (Intercept)         ggi      female  ggi:female 
#         ...         ...         ...         ... 

lm(pv1math ~ I(ggi*female), data=dat)$coefficients
# (Intercept) I(ggi * female) 
#         ...             ...
```

`I()` is useful e.g. for polynomials, where *age* is a popular candidate: `pv1math ~ age + I(age^2) + I(age^3)`, or to binarize a dependent variable in a GLM: `glm(I(pv1math > 0.75) ~ ggi*female, family=binomial)`.

And - [as *@G.Grothendieck* already wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58685874/6574038) - you don't need to repeat the variables that are already present in the interaction term (it's just redundant), so you may want to try:

```
lm(pv1math ~ ggi*female + factor(year) + female*factor(country), data=f1)
```